# C++ cout operand error, type error ostream, string

Tags: c++, types, cout

I'm just learning the basics of c++, and I'm having some problems with cout.  I wrote a few simple tests to print hello world, a simple adder function, and a function to flip the order of a string.  Everything runs fine except my string function that gives my this error.  Would love an explanation, thanks.

Error: no operator "<<" matches these operands, operand types are std:ostream << std:string

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int adder(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int addOneToInput(int a)
{
return a + 1;
}

string flipStringOrder(string s)
{
string temp = "";
for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i ++)
{
    char charTemp = (s.at(s.length() - i -1));
    temp += charTemp;
}
return temp;
}


void main(){
cout << "Hello World" << endl;
int x = 5;
int y = 3;
cout << adder(x, y) << endl;
cout << flipStringOrder("moon") << endl;
cin.get();
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to have #included <string>...

Comment: `void main` is not a legal signature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to:

```
#include <string>
```

You should never rely on relevant standard headers to be included indirectly through the inclusion of other headers.

Also, change the signature of `main()` into a legal one, for instance:

```
int main()
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: O, that did it, thanks.  What do you mean change the signature of main into a legal one?  Can't i just use void, im not returning anything anyway.  I'm a bit used to java's public static void  main, there's an advantage to using int?

Comment: Also, is there any reason main would be evaluated if it were an int?  would I have to call main to start the program?

Comment: @user2426318: `void main()` is not a legal signature, while `int main()` is. You are allowed to have no `return` statement in `main()`, that is equivalent to `return 0` (which indicates success). Any value different from `0` would indicate failure.